# How can a super consciousness contend with the erasure of a soul?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, gods, consciousness

What we call "God" is actually a catch all term for the human consciousness, which we are all apart of. This super consciousness is connected to all human souls, and binds us together on a lower level that we are subconsciously aware of, hence some concept of God existing in all cultures. When we die, our souls fade into this god and become one with it. Everything that has happened or will happen exists all at once in this "God", as it serves as a database for human existence.

There are 5 parts that make up a soul, which are condensed into a stable form and held together by various spiritual components:

1. Raw mana- the life energy of the soul.
2. Ka- seat of a person's Emotions (love, fear, anger, etc)
3. Ba- seat of a person's memories
4. Sed- a person's spiritual I.D. (how the universe identifies and keeps track of them.
5. Un- the connector that binds their soul to their physical body and the physical realm.

By separating the soul into its parts and breaking them down into their originial elements, one can reconstruct their own soul. Through magical means, a person can reincarnate themselves using the soul remains of another. The method is used by less scrupulous mage as a way to cheat death. This glitch in the system essentially wipes a person from the super consciousness, which means that they never could have existed in the first place. This is akin to re-imaging a hard drive, installing a new operating system while completely erasing the old one.

The problem with this is that people are tied with those individuals. Friends, family, loved ones, etc., are all part of a person's memories. Everyone you meet becomes part of your history. Beyond this, certain events happen around or even because of individuals. People become significant to events in some way. The larger those events are, the more people they affect, the more etched they are into our conscious minds.

How can I get around this contradiction?

Answer (score 5):

### It's a super-conscious crisis

The super consciousness will be able to detect erasure in some way, regardless of how you go about it.  The only way to "deep erase" would be to steal other people's memories and erase them too.  However that still leaves contradictions (erasing a man's wife makes it weird when he magically has a baby one day; the memories of the child are odd without the mother, etc). Furthermore, there is the physical side of things: photographs, clothes, descendants, etc.  No matter which way you play it, this is probably better framed as a crisis of some kind for the super-consciousness.

In other words, the super-consciousness figures out that something is wrong, but doesn't necessarily know how to go about solving the problem.

Without access to the Ba or the Mana, the super-consciousness can't re-implement the person's private moments or memories.  Maybe it can piece together a rough estimation of the Ka or Sed from other people's memories, but the private ones can't.

This crisis might manifest itself in a number of ways:

- A deep sense of being unwell beginning to emerge in certain populations.  This might be an explanation for higher suicide rates, sicknesses, crimes, etc.
- Interacting with the reincarnation causes the memories of that person to haunt the dreams of their loved ones.
- Errors: people have the memories of their loved ones, but when they interact with the reincarnations no one who is still a part of the super-consciousness can see their face or hear their voice (or it's muddled).  This might be interpreted by some as the reincarnations being "demons" because of their disfigured appearance and interaction.
- When the super-conscious interacts with the spiritual energy of the reincarnations, it tries to re-incorporate the energy.  That could mean anything from sucking the soul out of the person to uncontrollable rage / murderous intent by some people to kill the body so the soul can be re-uinited with the consciousness.  Perhaps this even leads to a war between the super-conscious and the reincarnated souls.
- The reincarnated souls end up forming a *second* super-conscious, and although the people of each are unaware, the two consciousnesses can talk and interact as we talk and interact with each other.  This might lead to them falling in love, spawning more, fighting, or so on.

Comment: These are great options! To determine what happens, you'll want to consider why the reincarnation happened in the first place. Was it a malicious act, desperate act, loving act, or an accident? If it was an accident, all those connections severing would be like a database with a bad reference. Anytime you try to recall the severed person, you have a small psychotic break because your brain/soul is glitching.

Comment: These glitchs/errors could also manifest or be experienced as intense dejavu or mandela effects.

Answer (score 0):

If we see the "god" as a database and the individual soul as tables from that database, one can extract the information from the table that is needed (for example the raw mana).

Unless one take all the parts that makes the soul (i suppose) the soul is not erase from the super consciousness.

In common sense, if a mage wants to extend his/her lifespan using the glitch, he/she just have to take the raw mana instead of the other parts (that of course given the case that the mage wants to impersonate other one).

If taking a part of the soul from this "database" stars a domino effect that eliminates the soul, then the consciousness can transport the rest of the data to another database (another dimension or a blocked "noosphere") that can be interacted with if enough powers are exerted.